# How to export a predefined function using snowfall?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, export, snowfall

I was trying to run some simulations in 4 cores using snowfall package. I have used `'mgcv'` library and its `'rmvn'` function to simulate some multivariate data within a user defined function. I called snowfall package in another user defined function, and used `'sfExpotAll'` to export all the variables in global environment. But it gave an error saying `"could not find function "rmvn"`".

Then I used `sfExport('rmvn')` to export it seperately, but then it gives an error saying, `"Unknown/unfound variable rmvn in export"`.

I wonder where I have made the mistake. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: in your case you need to export the library. so use `sfLibrary("mgcv")`

Comment: @user3293236 Thanks :D It worked.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer. If somebody else finds themselves here. You can check it as answered, if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load a library use:

```
sfLibrary("mgcv")
```

If you want to source a file use:

```
sfSource(pathtofile)
```